# in_array function returns true when passing empty array

Tags: php

I noticed the following strange occurrence:

```
var_dump(in_array("test", array_keys(array("hello"))));
```

Yields: `bool(true)`

How is this possible? Array does not contains keys, therefore `array_keys()` will return an empty array. Test is not in this empty array, so why would it return true? Is this a bug in PHP?

Comment: `array_keys(array("hello")))` is `[0]`, it's not empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple answer: loose typing, `'test' == 0`

Use

```
var_dump(in_array("test", array_keys(array("hello")), true));
```

for strict typing

And ***all*** arrays have keys, if you don't explicitly assign a key, then PHP will assign one based on incrementing integers from 0 (hence `'test' == 0`).... array_keys() will not be empty, because PHP will assign a key of `0` to your array entry of `"hello"`

Comment: Actually forgot that arrays of course always have keys.. stupid. Thanks